# Counter Strike 1.6 - How to modify the limit of grenade allowed to carry?

Tags: counter-strike

In counter strike 1.6, you can carry 1 grenade, 2 flash, 1 smoke. I want to carry more. Is there any way I can modify these numbers?

Note: I just play with bots.

Answer (score 2):

You can only do this using mods. Unlike in CS:GO there is no way of doing this with commands in CS 1.6.

If you can host a local server with AMX you can try [this plugin](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=24330) for example. I'm not sure how well it works, but it claims to do exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank, but I can't test this mod because I don't have AMX, I was hoping it was simply change numbers in a cfg file with text editor, then I can use Cheat Engine to track the address of the numbers. Guess I give up then. Thanks for your help.